# MYSQL to PDF is blank

Tags: php, mysql, pdf

```
  <?php
    require_once("connection.php");
    $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM personal_details");
    $header = mysql_query("SELECT `COLUMN_NAME` 
    FROM `INFORMATION_SCHEMA`.`COLUMNS` 
    WHERE `TABLE_SCHEMA`='unania' 
    AND `TABLE_NAME`='personal_details'");

    require('fpdf.php');
    $pdf = new FPDF();
    $pdf->AddPage();
    $pdf->SetFont('Arial','B',12);      
    foreach($header as $heading) {
    foreach($heading as $column_heading)
      $pdf->Cell(90,12,$column_heading,1);
    }
    foreach($result as $row) {
    $pdf->SetFont('Arial','',12);   
    $pdf->Ln();
    foreach($row as $column)
      $pdf->Cell(90,12,$column,1);
    }
    $pdf->Output();
    ?>
```

The above code when run outputs a blank PDF document, what is wrong, is it that I am using procedural mysql instead of OOP. However, I need a solution as quick as possible.

Comment: Have you tried putting a simple Text line in your PDF? What happens then? Maybe your foreach loops are not entered.

Comment: Tried what you just said and it is still blank. This is what i changed;            $result = "Game on";
$header = "Charlie";

Comment: Ok. Then it is not a problem with mysql. Leave the Test line in your Code an refresh your Browser with Shift + F5. Sometimes the old Page is cached.

Comment: It still didn't work. Thanks for your help, but if you have implemented such before, can you show me an example of how you did it and i'll be able to find something from it. Thanks

Comment: I just searched on Google and I had an example. Did you try it on your Webserver and on localhost? Maybe there is something wrong.

Comment: I tried it on localhost, i develop via localhost first, then upload to webserver.

Comment: @etalon11, have you discovered anything else from your Google findings?

Comment: No, but make a Test on your Webserver. Maybe something is wrong with your local Installation.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/100261/discussion-between-optimalresource-and-etalon11).

Comment: Could you already Check my solution? Seems that we are in different time zones ;-)

Answer (score 0):

I invested the time to make you a small sample with pdo. 
Somehow your errors are not shown in your localhost-system. You have to analyse this. Here is a sample which works for me:

```
<?php
require('fpdf.php');

$db = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=test;charset=utf8', 'root', '');
$db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

$colNames = array();

foreach($db->query("SELECT * FROM mytest") as $row2) {
    echo $row2['id'].' '.$row2['name'];
}

$result = $db->query("SELECT COLUMN_NAME FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA='test' AND TABLE_NAME='mytest'");

 foreach($result as $row) {
    $colNames[]  = $row["COLUMN_NAME"];
 }

$pdf = new FPDF();
$pdf->AddPage();
$pdf->SetDisplayMode(real,'default');

$pdf->SetFont('Arial','B',12);      
$pdf->SetTextColor(50,60,100);

$pdf->SetXY(50,20);
$pdf->SetDrawColor(50,60,100);
$pdf->Cell(100,10,'Tabledata MyTest',1,0,'C',0);

$pdf->Ln();
$pdf->Ln();

foreach($colNames as $colName) {
    $pdf->Cell(90,12,$colName,1);
}

$pdf->Ln();

foreach($db->query("SELECT * FROM mytest") as $row) {
   $pdf->Ln();
   foreach($colNames as $colName) {
      $pdf->Cell(90,12,$row[$colName],1);
    } 
}

ob_end_clean();
$pdf->Output();

?>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, i'll try implementing it right away

Comment: Have you been successful?

Comment: Yes i have, using PDO, it worked fine by populating the arrays as expected and the pdf was created good, i only applied your PDO database connection to my own script. But there is another problem am fighting with at the moment, the header and result was printed in duplicated form each. I resolved the header duplication from the code, but the result is duplicated across the header columns, like id printed twice and so on and so forth. I'll paste the new code below.

Comment: Please do not post your Code as an answer. Please expand your question with the code

Comment: Could you also Show us the PDF you generated?

Comment: Alright, i've posted the picture just now, the picture will give you an idea of what is going on. Visit www.hygres.com and scroll down to see it

Comment: Your foreach-loops are wrong. At first you have to loop over your selected rows. After this you have to loop over all your columns. And then you print out every value for every column in a row. Try it.

Comment: Wonderful bro, its working very well now, i checked your foreach-loops and discovered where it all went wrong. Thanks a lot. Please i have been searching for a while how to mark your answer as the correct one, how do i do that?

Comment: @optimalresource A rating of my question would be nice. Thanks.